# Extract the data from a Web Page which has more Textual Content using beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to extract the data rich nodes of a web page . Is there a way to extract the text from the webpage

```
import requests
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url = "http://www.amazon.in"
r = requests.get(url)
html = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
print html.title.text
```

I can print the title of the webpage ,can you please help me to extract the text(only text) in the webpage.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this

```
import requests
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
html = urllib.urlopen('http://www.amazon.in').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
texts = soup.findAll(text=True)

def visible(element):
    if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', '[document]', 'head', 'title']:
    return False
elif re.match('<!--.*-->', str(element)):
    return False
return True

visible_texts = filter(visible, texts)
print visible_texts
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import requests
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url = "http://www.amazon.in"
r = requests.get(url)
html = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
print html.get_text()
```